# Access to a value inside a form in a scala template

Tags: playframework-2.0

What is wrong with this scala template?

```
@(tankForm: Form[Tank])

@{id : tankForm.data.getOrElse("id", "")}
```

I need to use something like this because id might not have a value. Thus tankForm("id").value would throw a NullPointerException.

I could use an if statement but i'd like to learn to use this crazy syntax scala proposes us... And I think there's an elegant way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the right line is not so crazy after all :

```
@id = @{if(tankForm("id").value != null) tankForm("id").value else ""}
```

I'm almost disappointed ;)